# Sum elements on a nested hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm using MongoDB to store aggregated information. Something similar to the following hash where we can see how how many customers there is grouping them by gender, age and region (the real data structure have 5 levels):

```
customers = {
  male: {
    young: {
      european: 1, 
      american: 2,
    },
    adult: {
      european: 3,
      american: 4,
    },
    senior: {
      european: 5,
      american: 6,
    }
  },
  female: {
    young: {
      european: 7,
      american: 8,
    },
    adult: {
      european: 9,
      american: 10,
    },
    senior: {
      european: 11,
      american: 12
    }
  }
}
```

Business dudes loves to have access to every bit of information. Considering this, I'm trying to write a method that receives an hash like this, an array of nested levels and the nested attribute they want to query to return how much customers of that type there is.

Example: If we want to retrieve the number of young customers, the boilerplate should be something like this:

```
levels = %i(gender age region)
young_custumers = sum_method(customers, levels, {age: :young})
```

This should return the number of young customers: 18

Anyone knows an elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach you may wish to consider.

**Code**

```
def sum_em(h, filter)
  f = filter.first
  f = h.keys if f == :all
  if h[f.first].is_a? Hash
     f.reduce(0) { |t,k| t+sum_em(h[k], filter.drop(1)) } 
  else
     f.reduce(0) { |t,k| t+h[k] }
  end
end
```

**Examples**

These examples are for your hash `customers`.

```
sum_em customers, [:all,      [:young],         :all]        #=> 18
sum_em customers, [[:male],   [:young],         :all]        #=>  3
sum_em customers, [[:female], [:young],         :all]        #=> 15
sum_em customers, [:all,      [:young, :adult], [:american]] #=> 24
sum_em customers, [:all,      :all,             [:american]] #=> 42
sum_em customers, [:all,      :all,             :all]        #=> 78
```

This of course works for any number of levels.